# 2 .onReceive() functions with timers not working

Tags: swift, animation, timer, swiftui

So essentially I have the view shown below. "movingObject" should be moving around randomly while the ProgressView loads. "stationaryobject" is essentially just a background image. For some reason, only the ProgressView .onReceive() is working. When I remove that .onReceive(), it makes the random animation work correctly. I also tried changing the order of the .onReceive() functions to see if that had an effect but it didn't. I'm thinking maybe I can't have two timers in the same view?

```
struct LoadingView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var appState: AppState
    
    var body: some View {
        
        let timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.045, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
        let timerForAnimation = Timer.publish(every: 1, tolerance: 0.1, on: .main,in: .common).autoconnect()
        
        VStack {
            ZStack{
                Image("stationaryobject")
                    .scaleEffect(0.25)
                    .frame(width: 213, height: 131)
                Image("movingObject")
                    .scaleEffect(0.05)
                    .frame(width: 56, height: 75)
                    .offset(appState.offset)
            }
            ProgressView("", value: appState.progress, total: 100)
                .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.7)
            Text("Loading...")
        }
        .onReceive(timerForAnimation) { _ in
            let widthBound = CGFloat(50)
            let heightBound = CGFloat(30)
            let randomOffset = CGSize(
                width: CGFloat.random(in: -widthBound...widthBound),
                height: CGFloat.random(in: -heightBound...heightBound)
            )
            withAnimation {
                self.appState.offset = randomOffset
            }
        }
        .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            if appState.progress < 100 {
                appState.progress += 0.5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the `.onReceive(timer)` modifier under the ZStack container. The two will be working by doing so as just one modifier can work at a time if they are under the same container.